# Cyberlink library for working with upnp devices

Tags: ios4, upnp

I am working with iPhone Cyberlink library for upnp detection.

I am working with upnp devices for creating the home automation. I am making posting action for the same but in some cases I want to get the response of those actions and parse it to fetch the values from those.

Answer (score 1):

See the UPnP Forum's device architecture docs at http://upnp.org/sdcps-and-certification/standards/device-architecture-documents/ for a description of the format of responses to action invocations.

Alternatively, you could consider switching your development to [ohNet](http://wiki.openhome.org/wiki/OhNet) which will present you a C++ class per service with a sync/async function per action.  This allows you to concentrate on your application development without worrying about the details of the UPnP protocol.

(Disclaimer: I have contributed to this project)